# In TestNG in @AfterMethod how can I know the test result?

Tags: java, testing, listener, testng

I have a number of TestNG test classes that all extend one base class `AbstractIntegrationTest`. In the superclass I have a mehod `commonAfterMethod` which is invoked after each test method and performs some clean-up.

What I want is to do in this method something depending on the test result, e.g. if the test fails, I want to dump the test data into a file for further investigation. The problem is that I need to do it exactly in `commonAfterMethod` because it performs a roll-back on the database and the data is lost afterwards.

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can do something with a test listener instead?  See [ITestListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestListener.html) and [IInvokedMethodListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IInvokedMethodListener.html).

Answer (score 1):

Pass in the ITestResult object in the afterMethod method.

```
@AfterMethod()
public void afterMethod(ITestResult result){
    if(!result.isSuccess()){
        //Do stuff here if it failed
    }
}
```